# Handling Null Date in an Entity Framework query

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, datetime, linq-to-entities

Please am pulling some data from the database using linq to entities.From the query result i make a collection and bind to a gridview control.Problem is on one of the date column from the database some of the values are null and when i do a tostring it gives me an exception. Below is the first query i used to get the data ferom the database.

```
    Dim sSession = From ses In DemoSchool.Terms
                   Select New With {Key .Session = ses.Session,
                                    Key .Term = ses.Term1,
                                    Key .StartDate = ses.StartDate,
                                    Key .EndDate = ses.EndDate,
                                    Key .NextTerm = ses.NextTerm}
```

Then from this result i do a select to get the columns so that i can apply formating to the datetime column

```
  Dim query = (From estty In sSession Select estty).ToList() _
              .Select(Function(essty) New With {.Session = essty.Session,
                                 .Term = essty.Term,
                                 .StartDate = essty.StartDate.ToString("ddd d MMM yyyy"),
                                 .EndDate = CDate(essty.EndDate).ToString("ddd d MMM yyyy"),
                                 .NextTerm = CDate(essty.NextTerm).ToString("ddd d MMM yyyy")})
```

the problem comes from the last two statement because this column in the database contains null values and i thought CDate method was going to work but it turns out i was wrong.
    (This is where the error is being thrown)   .EndDate = CDate(essty.EndDate).ToString("ddd d MMM yyyy"),
                                     .NextTerm = CDate(essty.NextTerm).ToString("ddd d MMM yyyy")})

The second query result is bounded to a gridview like so
    grdShowSession.DataSource = query
    grdShowSession.DataBind()
The error shown is Nullable object must have a value. Please i need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo could make a function that returns a string with the element like

```
Function returnElementString As String(element As Objec)
    If IsNothing(element) Then
       return "whatever"
    Else 
       return CDate(element).ToString("ddd d MMM yyyy")
    End If
End Function
```

and in you code you'll use as example:

```
.EndDate = returnElementString(essty.EndDate)
```